# Is it possible to embed {{ctx.trigger.scheduled_time}} variable in the reporting url inside a watcher script?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-painless, elasticsearch-watcher

I have deployed a watcher script that triggered for certain search criteria. The action of the watch is to generate a dashboard.pdf and send it through email.

Now the problem is, I'm using two systems for this alert, one is watcher to trigger the alert and another is Kibana Reporting which generates the pdf report. Now for watcher triggering time is stored in {{ctx.trigger.scheduled_time}} variable but in the POST url, we are using "now". Because of this there is a mismatch found between the results of these two systems.

Please see below the watcher snippet.

```
"filter": {
                "range": {
                  "transaction_datetime": {
                    "gte": "{{ctx.trigger.scheduled_time}}||-5m",
                    "lte": "{{ctx.trigger.scheduled_time}}",
                    "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                  }
```

and below is the POST url snippet.

```
time%3A%28from%3Anow-5m%2Cto%3Anow%29
```

Now I'm trying to embed {{ctx.trigger.scheduled_time}} variable in the POST url so that both the systems will be in sync.

Is there any way by which I can embed the variable value into the POST url?

If you need more details regarding the logic or watcher script, please let me know.

Please help.

Edited:

I have tried to embed the variable in the POST URL as below.

```
http://XXX.XX.X.XX:5601/s/watcher-alerting/api/reporting/generate/printablePdf?jobParams=(browserTimezone:UTC,layout:(dimensions:(height:1576,width:1287),id:preserve_layout),objectType:dashboard,relativeUrls:!('/s/watcher-alerting/app/dashboards#/view/....c?_g=(filters:!!(),refreshInterval:(pause:!!f,value:60000),time:(from:{{ctx.trigger.scheduled_time}}-5m,to:{{ctx.trigger.scheduled_time}}))&_a=(description:!'For watcher alert!!!'s attachment.!',filters:!!(),fullScreenMode:!!f,options:(hidePanelTitles:!!f,useMargins:!!t),panels:!!((embeddableConfig:(enhancements:()),gridData:(h:56,i:....,w:48,x:0,y:0),id:....,panelIndex:....,type:visualization,version:!'7.11.1!')),query:(language:kuery,query:!'!'),tags:!!(),timeRestore:!!t,title:!'Watcher Dashboard!',viewMode:view)'),title:'PDF Report')
```

The above is the decoded version of the URL, removed some of the information for security reason.

With this URL, watcher is working but found the same lag of few seconds (4-5 Seconds) between the triggered_time found in watcher output and the "to time" found in the above of the pdf report, which should match to fullfil my objective. I believe I'm making sense, if it is not clear, please let me know.

Comment: In the documentation it shows explicitly that you can use mustache template in the path for a webhook https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/actions-webhook.html#configuring-webook-actions

Comment: So I believe your issue to be with url encoding ?

Comment: If so, I think you may want to use mustache url helper function https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/search-template.html#search-template-url-encode-strings

Comment: I have seen the link you shared in "Search Template" and seems it is related to the query we do in elasticsearch for the watch to trigger. But with the help of that, is it possible to add the watcher variable i.e., {{ctx.trigger.scheduled_time}} inside the URL that triggers the reporting module to generate the csv? Please excuse if I made any improper statements.

Comment: I think you should share in your question what you would like to achieve, even if it does not work so we can better understand your target

Comment: Sure @Paulo, I have updated the question, please check once. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I tried on my side to reproduce the error and I could not. My report is generated with the right range of date down the the second.